# How to mkdir with ls and pipeline

Tags: shell

For example, there are directories like the following.

```
AAA/dir1
AAA/dir2
AAA/dir3
```

How do I make the directories with the same name in another root directory, using shell commands and pipeline?

```
BBB/dir1
BBB/dir2
BBB/dir2
```

Comment: Easy way is `for i in AAA/dir*/; do mkdir -p "${i/AAA/BBB}"; done` (note: this presumes there is only one `AAA` in the original filenames, or that you just want to replace the first occurrence with `BBB`) It also presumes your last `BBB/dir2` is supposed to be `BBB/dir3`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand that you have a single level of directories under the present working directory `./AAA` and you want to duplicate the directory structure for the first level of directories under `AAA` named `dir1, dir2, ...` under the new directory `BBB` in the present working directory, then all you need is a `for` loop and `mkdir -p`. No pipelines or `ls` required.

When you want to select directories (as opposed to files and directories) with a `for` loop, you append a trailing `'/'` to your glob. For example, to select all first-level directories under the current, you can use:

```
for dir in */; do
```

That will allow you to iterate over the directory names in the variable `dir`. (excluding hidden directories that begin with a `'.'`)

In this question, you want to add a constraint that you want to select the first level directories under `AAA` named `dir*` (or `dir[0-9]*` to be precise - to avoid selecting any `AAA/dirnotnumbered`). So you simply add the constraints to your directory selection, e.g.

```
for dir in AAA/dir[0-9]*/; do
```

POSIX shell provide for a parameter expansion with substring replacement of the form `${var/find/replace}` to replace the first occurrence of `find` in `$var` with `replace`. You can use that to find `AAA` and replace it with `BBB`.

All that remains is calling `mkdir -p` on the new name with `BBB` in place of `AAA`, e.g.

```
for dir in AAA/dir[0-9]*/; do
    mkdir -p "${dir/AAA/BBB}"
done
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.